# how to print the contents of a repository and make a repository on a REST server?

Tags: java, rest, uri

I'm starting to design a RESTful server with Java, using the Httpserver class. I have a couple of tasks to do let's start with one:

The user must be able to discover the uri with a Read (GET) call to a predefined URI: "/index"
Like this: GET /index -> {/a, /b, /c}

everything is contained in a repository (a folder), how do I link that folder to / index?

probably it's a simple thing, but I don't know where to start, I accept advice and even sources that you can consult. Thank you

I created the server and it works, I leave you the code server code[server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lOEH.png)

I also created an index page where I put all the call handling for the index page into it
[indexPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBOPs.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do this

- HATEOAS describes a way to return links as part of a response - see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS
- you could also use OpenAPI to provide documentation for your apis to describe what apis are available https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/